# Microsoft Terminal Services

Tags: .net, terminal-services

Any idea about opening a remote app (Microsoft Terminal Services) on client through .Net?

Answer (score 1):

Just create an RDP file, write it to disk and launch mstsc with the rdp file as parameter.

For a remoteapp the following lines are important (here in sample for MSPaint):

```
remoteapplicationmode:i:1
alternate shell:s:||mspaint
remoteapplicationprogram:s:||mspaint
remoteapplicationname:s:Paint
```